# How to Differentiate Colours In Bar Graph In Each Bar in Asp.Net C# Chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph, charts

i am developing web application in asp.net c#, in it i am using chart (bar graph), in this bar graph all bars in the same colors, but i want to display customized colors in each bar, but i don't know how to display, any one let me know the code how to differentiate.

**now the below graph showing all blue.**

**but iam expecting each bar is in separate colour.**

[image]

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" Width="450px" Height="350px">
<Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartArea="ChartArea1">
 </asp:Series>
</Series>
<ChartAreas>
   <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
     <Area3DStyle WallWidth="1" LightStyle="Realistic"></Area3DStyle>
   </asp:ChartArea>
 </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

**C#**

```
Chart2.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];

Chart2.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Days";
Chart2.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Count";

Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
Chart2.Series["Series1"].Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#418cf0");
Chart2.Series["Series1"].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
Chart2.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
Chart2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Found The Answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6440711/5772054

```
Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.Green, Color.LightGreen, Color.YellowGreen, Color.Yellow, Color.Maroon, Color.Red };
foreach (Series series in Chart2.Series)
  {
    foreach (DataPoint point in series.Points)
     {
       //point.LabelBackColor = colors[series.Points.IndexOf(point)];
       point.Color = colors[series.Points.IndexOf(point)];
     }
  }
```